# IE11 XHR failing to set ContentType=multipart/form-data while using FormData/Ajax to upload a file

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

My file is not posting using FormData in jquery.ajax(). Server treats POST as GET as probably request data gets corrupted.

In F12 Developer Tools > Network, **"Request Body" pane tells "data could not be rendered"**. **Request Header has Content-Length but no Content-Type**! Firebug shows both and it works in FF. If I remove the line that send file, a normal Form can be posted properly and it show in Network tab.

EmulateIE10 does not work either & EMulateIE9 works but it does not support multiple file upload.

Code is as follows:

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(firstAJAX); // overrides submit
```

...

```
function firstAJAX(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // loop through selected file
    //MAKE A unique AJAX REQUEST to create a record, return ID, call secondAJAX(ID) for each first request
```

...

```
function secondAJAX(response, params) {
   // after making sure firstAJAX was successful.
   ...
   var formData = new FormData();
   var key = $(response).find("#keyx").text();
   formData.append('file1', $('#file1')[0].files[params.idx], $('#file1')[0].files[params.idx].name);
   formData.append('dockey', key);

    $.ajax({
                url: 'global file processor with FULL URL',
                type: 'POST',  

                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                index: params.index,

                success: function(data) {

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
}
```

So far  I've tried following:

- Sending an extra form field with name/value at the end of the form as mentioned in http://bit.ly/1tOgPve
- Posting to absolute URL (same domain, of course)
- setting contentType, processData to false
- even got rid of firstAJAX and called secondAJAX directly in response to user pressing form submit button
- used XHR directly w/o jquery but same result
- tweaked character encoding
- set KeepAlive off in aPache
- uninstalled IE11, previous was IE8, then installed IE10, tested but no luck, installed IE11 afresh

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks.

PS: I don't have access to server side code at the moment, but the thing is that same code is working on FF. I've usual firewall and stuff but nothing extra-ordinary. The server side code is apache/jboss/jsp probably.

> UPDATE: It seems to me that either Apache/jboss/SSL/SSO authentiaction is acting up while exchanging information with IE and that is what is making IE give up in communication. Tried a sample code with C# in a new project. Everything works fine in IE11!
>
> Do you people suggest I post it to superuser.com then?

..

> UPDATE2: It is definitely XHR that is acting up. I can use a typical  post but NETWORK shows correct Content-Type header but its not sent while using XHR.send()

Comment: Have you tried setting the content mime type of the file prior to uploading to see if that helps?   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: @BobTate - tried that, even FF code stopped working. 

also tried mimeType and beforeSend as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: What's the value of `key`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - Nope, its like XYZ.JPG_CUST_ENV_PROJ! At this point, I really wish it is something that silly.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. The issue is awfully similar to the one described in the blog post you linked to though. I would try to intercept the request as described in that post, and see if anything's off with the MIME boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested, I was able to fix the issue. Turned out that code was including Sarissa library that was overriding IE's default XMLHttpRequest object with an old MSXML ActiveX object. Tweaked that code and it all started working.

Thanks for looking into the problem.